# How to send data NextJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am trying to send data from a form to mongo DB but the data comes back as undefined using nextJS and MongoDB.

**NewPlayerPage** component:

```
const newPlayerPage = (props) => {
    console.log('props: ' + props);

    const handleAddPlayer = async (enteredPlayerData) => {
        
        const response = await fetch('/api/new-player', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(enteredPlayerData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        });

        const data = response.json();
        router.replace('/teams/' + router.query.teamId);

        alert('Player ' + enteredPlayerData.playerFName + ' created!');
    };

    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>New player page</h2>
            <h3>TeamID: {router.query.teamId}</h3>
            <NewPlayer teamId={router.query.teamId} onAddPlayer={handleAddPlayer} />
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

**NewPlayer** component:

```
const newPlayer = (props) => {
    const playerFNameInput = useRef();
    const playerLNameInput = useRef();
    const teamId = props.teamId;

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const enteredPlayerFName = playerFNameInput.current.value;
        const enteredPlayerLName = playerLNameInput.current.value;

        const playerData = {
            teamId: teamId,

            playerName: {
                playerFName: enteredPlayerFName,
                playerLName: enteredPlayerLName,
            },
        };
        props.onAddPlayer(playerData);
    };
    return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h3>Team: {props.teamName}</h3>
                <div className={classes.control}>
                    <label htmlFor='playerFName'>Player First Name</label>
            <input type='text' required id='playerFName' ref {playerFNameInput} />
                    <label htmlFor='playerLName'>Player Last Name</label>
            <input type='text' required id='playerLName' ref={playerLNameInput} />
                </div>
                <h3>TeamId: {props.teamId}</h3>
                <div className={classes.actions}>
                    <button>Create Player</button>
                </div>
            </form>
    );
};
```

I want to send data from the form to the mongoDB backend but the data keeps being sent as undefined.

Comment: we need to see your backend code too

Comment: can you share please the backend code and et output of "enteredPlayerData"

Answer (score 0):

Bro you didn't pass the parameter in the `handleAddPlayer` function(arrow function) in `NewPlayerPage` page. So, how can data can be send if its not coming inside the function.

`In NewPlayerPage`

````
const newPlayerPage = (props) => {
    console.log('props: ' + props);

    const handleAddPlayer = async (enteredPlayerData) => {
        
        const response = await fetch('/api/new-player', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(enteredPlayerData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        });

        const data = response.json();
        router.replace('/teams/' + router.query.teamId);

        alert('Player ' + enteredPlayerData.playerFName + ' created!');
    };

    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>New player page</h2>
            <h3>TeamID: {router.query.teamId}</h3>
           <NewPlayer teamId={router.query.teamId} onAddPlayer={()=> handleAddPlayer(YourParameters) } />
        </Fragment>
    );
};```
````